# Maximum minimum values in trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

> Find minimum value of $2\sin^2a+3\cos^2a$

Solving it we get $2+ \cos^2a$

> Answer: $3$ (taking $\cos a$ as $-1$)

Why are we using the minimum cosine value as $-1$ instead of using the cosine as $0$?

This can make the minimum value as $2$.

Comment: This site uses 
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: You're right: $3$ is the *maximum* value.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: since
$$
2\sin^2a+3\cos^2a=2+\cos^2a
$$
and the cosine squared has maximum value $1$ and minimum value $0$, the minimum value of the expression is $2$ (computed for $a=\pi/2$) and maximum value $3$ (computed for $a=0$).

Comment: +1 but.. $\cos(0)=1$ ;)

Comment: @kamil09875 Oops! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$2 \sin^2a+3 \cos^2 a= 3\cos^2a+2-2\cos^2 a=\cos^2a+2$$
$$0\le \cos^2a \le 1 \Rightarrow 2\le \cos^2a+2 \le 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the function to get $-2cos\alpha sin\alpha$ and set it to $0$. This gives $sin2\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Solution $\alpha=0$ doesn't help in finding the minimum.